# separating x and y information

Tags: image, matlab, csv

I'm trying to get my matlab script to separate X and Y into two files, but I'm not sure how to separate them. My code looks like this:

```
close all
clear all
clc

jpgFiles = dir('*.jpg');
numFiles = length(jpgFiles);
mydata = cell(1,numFiles);

% mydata = zeros(numFiles);
for k = 1:numFiles
    mydata{1,k} = imread(jpgFiles(k).name);
end
% initialize your array of coordinates
data = zeros(30,2,numFiles);

for k=1:numFiles
    figure;
    imshow(mydata{k});
    [x, y] = ginput(30) %select 30 points on the image and return the 
                        %xy coords in return
    data(:,:,k) = [x y]; %save the xy coords as data matrix 
end
%Get data into a csv text file for easy export to excel 
filename = 'test.csv';
csvwrite(filename,data)
```

i have tried to write  `"data(:,:,k) = [x y];"` into 2 lines, one with x and one with y but that doesn't work. 
Can anyone help me since it would save me a lot of time since i only need the Y information.

Answer (score 0):

With `[x y]` you concatenate the variables `x` and `y`, for example if

```
x = 
    1
    2
    3
```

and

```
y =
    3
    2
    1
```

, then `[x y]`  will result in

```
ans = 
    1    3
    2    2
    3    1
```

As you only need the `y` coordinate, simply *don't* do this ;-) Initialize `data` to have only 1 column, instead of two:

```
data = zeros(30,1,numFiles);
```

and write to it using

```
data(:,:,k) = y;
```

--

Alternatively, if you *do* need the `x` information for other purposes (I'm not 100% sure how your question was meant, so here's a way if you meant it that way), then you don't want to do the changes I proposed above. Instead, write only the second column of `data` to the CSV file, using

```
csvwrite(filename,data(:,2,:))
```

this means: take only the second column of `data`, and write it to `filename`.